# How to combine three separate interaction plots into a single figure?

Tags: r, plot, interaction

Apologies for that. Here's my question with a reproducible data set:

```
library(effects)
data(Arrests)

Arrests$year <- as.factor(Arrests$year)

arrests.mod <- glm(released ~ employed + citizen + checks + colour*year + 
                   colour*age, family=binomial, data=Arrests)

t.effects  <- allEffects(arrests.mod)

plot(t.effects, "colour:year")
plot(t.effects, "colour:age")
```

Is it possible to combine the two plots into a single figure?

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
```

This doesn't work. I.e. the figures are reproduced separately in two graphs, but not in the same figure.

Comment: What does `unfortunately doesn't not work` mean? Please make your situation reproducible, i.e. provide us with the data and the code needed to mimic your situation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more tips on how to do this.

Comment: You've got some rogue " in your code too - look at the coloring.

Comment: Sorry, I provided a better example above. Julia

Answer (score 3):

`par(mfrow=c(2,1))` don't work for grid plots. It is only for base graphics. You can use `gridExtra` to arrange lattice plots.

```
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- plot(t.effects, "colour:year")
p2 <- plot(t.effects, "colour:age")
grid.arrange(latticeGrob(p1),
            latticeGrob(p2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can reference specific effects from your alleffects object with vector indices. In your case I believe t.effects[4:5] or, equivalently, t.effects[c("colour:year", "colour:age")]

```
library(effects)
data(Arrests)

Arrests$year <- as.factor(Arrests$year)
arrests.mod <- glm(released ~ employed + citizen + checks + colour*year + colour*age, family=binomial, data=Arrests)
t.effects <- allEffects(arrests.mod)

plot(t.effects[4:5])
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. plot(t.effects[4:5])  still plots the two interactions separately (one after the other) - not in one figure.

Comment: That's odd, they're in the same plot for me.